# Understading this perfect forwarding example

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I came across the following example while attempting to understand what `std::forward` does

```
// forward example
#include <utility>      // std::forward
#include <iostream>     // std::cout

// function with lvalue and rvalue reference overloads:
void overloaded (const int& x) {std::cout << "[lvalue]";}
void overloaded (int&& x) {std::cout << "[rvalue]";}

// function template taking rvalue reference to deduced type:
template <class T> void fn (T&& x) {
  overloaded (x);                   // always an lvalue
  overloaded (std::forward<T>(x));  // rvalue if argument is rvalue
}

int main () {

  std::cout << "calling fn with rvalue: ";
  fn (0);
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is

> calling fn with rvalue: [lvalue][rvalue]

Now my question is how did we get `lvalue` first ? Here is my line of thought
in our `main` I called `fn(0);` Now 0 is rvalue. So the universal reference x is deduced to the following

```
void fn (int&& && x);
```

Now according to reference collapsing we would get

```
void fn (int&& x);
```

Thus making `x` behave like an rvalue.So if `x` is passed then rvalue overloaded method should be called. However it seems the other overloaded lvalue reference function is called. I would appreciate it if someone could clarify this

Comment: `x` itself is an lvalue. `x = 2;` is perfectly legal. You can't do that with an rvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *named* variable is NEVER an rvalue. It is invariably an lvalue. Rvalues are only *pure* expressions which don't have names.

```
int && i = int(0);
```

Here the expression `int(0)` is an rvalue, but the variable `i` itself is an lvalue, declared to be binding to an rvalue.